# Meaning of this regular expression?

Tags: regex

Hii can anyone tell me meaning of the given re?

```
pr\s+stats\s+(\d+)(?:hours|hrs)
```

i am confused about \s and \d soo i need explanation

Comment: The characters "pr" followed by at least one whitespace character, followed by "stats", followed by at least one whitespace character, followed by one or more digits (which are captured in a capture group), followed by either "hours" or "hrs".

Comment: look  [here](https://regex101.com/r/OuxLJ6/1) at the right panel to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this link to see what are the kind of strings that are matched by this regex: https://regex101.com/r/7LXIrb/1

Examples:

```
pr stats  123hours << matched
pr  stats 432hours << matched
pr stats 4hrs  << matched

pr
stats
1hrs
^^^^^^^
matched

#######    
pr


stats

199hrs
^^^^^^^
matched from pr
```

Explanations:

- `pr` followed by
- 1 or more "whitespace char" ( space, tab, newline, carriage return, vertical tab)
- followed by `stats`
- then 1 or more "whitespace char" ( space, tab, newline, carriage return, vertical tab)
- then one or more digits in a capturing group
- then in a non capturing group hours or hrs

reference for regex: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

Answer (score 0):

`pr` => the string contains 'pr'
`\s+` => it is followed by one or more space
`stats` => it is followed by the word 'stats'
`\s+` => it is followed by one or more space
`(\d+)` => it is followed by one or more digit (from 0 to 9)
`(?:hours|hrs)` => it is followed by the string 'hours' or the tring 'hrs'

Exemple of strings that would match :

```
pr stats 45hours

uifyerrpr stats 45hoursoudfghsofh

pr         stats    45hrs
```

Exemple of strings that would not match :

```
pr stats45 hours  

uifyerrprstats 45 hoursoudfghsofh

pr         stats     hrs

pr stats 45hour
```